# How to fix UnsatisfiedLinkError while calling Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()?

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin

I have just set up my openCV project according to [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) with version 3.4.3 and I have successfully compiled project, but I get this message

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.video.Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2_3() (tried Java_org_opencv_video_Video_createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2_13 and Java_org_opencv_video_Video_createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2_13__)
        at org.opencv.video.Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2_3(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.video.Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(Video.java:145)
        at com.example.maciej.imageprocessing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:80)
```

while calling `var backSub = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` whenever I am trying to create subtructor.

I'm new to openCV and It's my first time using native libraries in android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that some openCV library is loaded asynchronously, and `backSub = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` should be initialized insinde `onManagerConnected` method like this:

```
private val mLoaderCallback = object: BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        override fun onManagerConnected(status: Int) {
            when (status) {
                LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully")
                    mOpenCvCameraView?.enableView()
                    backSub = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
                }
                else -> {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status)
                }
            }
        }
}
```